# C# - Add List Count to JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Method that  creates `List<SomeObject>`.  The Collection is JSON serialized via `JavaScriptSerializer`.  I am using LINQ's skip/take to return a subset of the total collection.  So, I need to return the size of the **total collection** to the client as an object (this can't be calculated on the client side because it only has a subset).

I could hack it.  Just, add `int TotalSize` as a member of `SomeObject`.

I would rather not repeat this Member N times as I only need it once.  I also don't want to perform some terrible OO by adding a member which doesn't really belong to the class.

Is there anything else I can do in order to add this new member to my JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make a complex object?

```
public class SomeObjectSet
{
     public int TotalSetCount { get; set; }
     public List<SomeObject> Items { get; set; }

     public SomeObjectSet(List<SomeObject> subset, int totalCount)
     {
          items = subset;
          TotalSetCount = totalCount;
     }
}
```

Then, you simply make your new object and assign the data in the constructor, and your JSON should look like so:

```
{
     TotalSetCount: 100,
     Items: [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... }
     ]
}
```

And in code you would just do this:

```
 var subset = mySuperset.Skip(...).Take(...);
 var totalSetCount = mySuperSet.Count();

 var serialization = _javascriptSerializer.Serialize(new SomeObjectSet(subset, totalSetCount));
```

Comment: The Op was suggesting adding a new property `int TotalSize` to each `SomeObject` if I read it correctly. That seems ridiculous. =D